# ftp доступ к папкам c кирилицей

Tags: ftp, кириллица, configuration

На 2016 windows server в IIS10 поднят ftp 
Флаг Allow UTF8 = true;

Все папки внутри хранилища на русском языке.
При обращении к ресурсу через браузер возникают проблемы:
1) через хром часть символов превращаются в арабскую вязь (так и не смог точно определеить комбинацию), через IE 11 такой проблемы нет.
2) через любой браузер - если в имени папки присутвует буква "я" то папка недустпна и возникает ошибка

```
Не удается получить доступ к сайтуВеб-страница по адресу 
ftp://<address>/%D2%E5%F1%F2%EE%E2%E0%FF%20%EF%E0%EF%EA%E0/, 
возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу.
ERR_FTP_FAILED.
```

Если создать папку с именем из одной буквы "я", то никакого перхода по содержанию осуществляться не будет,а в адресной строке будет добавляться символ %FF/

В данном примере я обращался к адресу "Тестовая папка/" в корне ftp.

Возможно ли что-то сделать, чтобы корректно работать с кирилическими символами?